# Why doesn't my JavaFX slider event fire?

Tags: java, events, javafx

I'm trying to display the value of my slider when I am moving it around.

This is what I've tried so far but doesn't work:

```
public class ControlsController extends BaseController{
    @FXML
    private Slider slAcceleration;

    @FXML
    public void slAccelerationEventHandler(DragEvent event){
        System.out.println(slAcceleration.getValue());
    }
}
```

And my `.fxml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: bdc3ff;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.ControlsController">
   <children>
      <Label id="lbAcceleration" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="125.0" text="Versnelling simulatie x60" />
      <Slider id="slAcceleration" blockIncrement="1.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="151.0" max="600.0" min="1.0" onDragDone="#slAccelerationEventHandler" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="280.0" value="60.0" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Let me know if I should post more information. Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: what is not working here ?

Comment: @azro It just doesnt display the message in the console.

Comment: Change to : System.out.println("here "+slAcceleration.getValue());
just to know if it goes into the method for the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dragDone` event is part of the "drag and drop" system. It is called during full drag and drop processing (moving data around in your application, or between applications) and only happens if you have previously called `startDragAndDrop()` on some node.

What you need here is to observe the slider's [`valueProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#valueProperty). There is no event generated for that, so register the listener in the controller's `initialize` method:

```
public class ControlsController extends BaseController{
    @FXML
    private Slider slAcceleration;

    public void initialize() {
        slAcceleration.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println(newValue.doubleValue());
        });
    }
}
```

Note you also have errors in your FXML file: you are using `id` instead of `fx:id`. You need to fix this, otherwise the `@FXML`-injected fields in the controller will not be initialized.

Comment: Thank you James! I'm aware of the diffrence between id and fx:id, I just found that out.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's not the one you need. Property `onValueChange` does the trick, needing a `ChangeListener<Number>` signature for the handler (`Double` works too):

```
<Slider onValueChange="#doStuff"/>

@FXML
private void doStuff(ObservableValue<Number> ovn, Number before, Number after) {
    System.out.println(before+" "+after);
}
```